# recursive function for checking minimal number

Tags: recursion

My question is very simple, taught I'm not doing well with recursive functions.

Write a recursive function that scanning a natural sequence of numbers (n>0) until the stoppage condition of -1.
In case there are no numbers in the sequence, the program should print -1. 
(example: for the sequence of 5, 7, 8, 4, 3, 5, -1, the program should print 3.

So this is how far I got:

```
void Ex1() {
    printf("Enter sequence of numbers until -1");
    minimal_recursive_function();
}

int minimal_recursive_function() {
    int n, min;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    if ((min > n) && (n>0)) {
            min = n;
    }
    if (n == -1) {
        return min;
    }
    else {
        minimal_recursive_function(min);
    }
    printf("%d", min);
}
```

The program won't run ofcourse, since I don't have any value for min. I can't place n = min; as well.
*note - The recursive function shouldn't recieve any argument from other functions.

Would like to get hints, of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve your problem of not having an argument to pass the first time by treating the first iteration as a special case, and handling it separately before starting the recursion. That way, you can easily handle the exceptional case where no values are entered before -1, and you have a value to kick-start the recursion.

```
void Ex1() {
    int start;
    scanf("%d", &start);
    if (start == -1) printf("-1");
    else printf("%d", minimal(start));
}

int minimal(int min) {
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    if (n == -1) return min;
    if (n < min) min = n;
    return minimal(min);
}
```

Comment: I had to admit that I didn't understand the question correctly, and sadly that was my only mistake.